# How to cut off the power supply of the mouse, keyboard and speakers after shut down my computer?

Tags: mouse, power-management, shutdown

How to cut off the power supply of the mouse, keyboard and speakers after shut down my computer?

Although the computer is shut down, the light of mouse, keyboard and speakers are still here. It seems wasting energy.

How to tackle this problem?

---

***Thank you for your attention***

Comment: What is the make an model of your system?  When I shut down my systems, the mouse light is off.  Check your BIOS settings.

Comment: Is there any reference to help me set a proper setting?

Comment: Possibly, but I need to know the make and model of your system.

Comment: The motherboard is AsRock 960GC-GS-FX : http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/960GC-GS%20FX/. Thank you.

Comment: Check the USB Mouse Power On, under Advanced --> USB Configuration

Comment: USB 2.0 Controller, USB 2.0 Support, Legacy USB Suggort, USB Keyboard/Remote Power On and USB Mouse Power On are shown to me. What can I do?

Comment: Disable the USB Mouse Power On, see if that helps.

Comment: @Mitch - It seems ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

Your board is feeding power to the USB ports, so the fact that the power supply is plugged in, there are only two power states it can be in:

```
Standby (+5v)
On
```

Your USB ports run off of a +5V line.  Now, If you don't power off using the switch on the power supply (same as unplugging it), and as long as your USB mouse is plugged in, it will always be powered as long as the power supply is plugged in.

You could plug the power supply into a power strip and power it off that way. But the mouse light being on really won't hurt anything.